# Extracting Vcard information - R scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping

Is there a way to extract data from vcard using R? I am webscraping a few websites, one of them is - https://www.cwlaw.com/attorneys .

I need to collect the information from the vcard - the email.

Answer (score 1):

This is to extract the hrefs that have "mailto" and remmove it using gsub.

```
 gsub("mailto:", "",grep("mailto:", read_html("https://www.cwlaw.com/attorneys")%>% html_nodes("a")%>% html_attr("href"), value= T))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simple way you can extract the email address from a vcard.

This approach uses CURL to download the card, grep to find the line with string EMAIL, and finally stringr::str_split to capture the relevant part of the line.

```
library(curl)
library(stringr)

con <- curl('https://www.cwlaw.com/vcard-82.vcf', open='')
card <- readLines(con)
str_split(grep('EMAIL', card, value=TRUE), 'CP1252:')[[1]][2]
```